# The flatness of $A \otimes B$-module

Tags: homological-algebra

Let $A$ and $B$ be two finite dimensional $k$-algebra where $k$ is a field. Suppose that a left $A \otimes B$-module $H$ is flat as left $A$-module and flat as left $B$-module, I would like to know if $H$ is also flat as a left $A\otimes B$-module?

Comment: No. Take $A=B$ commutative, $H=A$, viewed as a $A\otimes _kA$-module via the multiplication map $A\otimes _kA\rightarrow A$.

Comment: @abx you want to assume something on $A=B$. Because if $A=B=k^n$ (direct power) every $(A\otimes B)$-module is projective. Probably more generally étale algebras have to be discarded.

Comment: @YCor: I think $A$ is a flat (= projective in this set-up) $A\otimes _kA$-module if and only if the $k$-algebra $A$ is absolutely semi-simple (see Bourbaki's Algèbre VIII, §13, Th. 2). So $A=k[x]/(x^2)$ does the job.